# How to create windows server backup (2008 R2) to the same drive?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-backup

I am not sure if the Windows server backup is the right tool but ... This what I am trying to achieve.

I have server and 2 drives C: and E:. E: drive is mirrored (2 hdds). I want to create scheduled backup to save the history of some tables. In case if somebody deletes from there - I'll be able to restore this data anytime (something like version controlling).

I am trying to use windows server backup but it do not let me to backup files to the same disk drive. I must choose another one there.

How to achieve my plan?

Comment: You achieve your plan by using a tool with more flexability then the built-in backup functionality within Windows.  But you do understand this is still a bad idea right?  While your system is in a RAID backing up the system to itself isn't a proper backup, using a RAID array is not meant to be a backup, its to allow drivers to fail ( if its allowed ) so data loss does not happen but you have to protect yourself from both drives failing.

Comment: I understand why is it not the best idea. But anyway, thanks.